# Oracle Apex 5 for web application

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have Oracle database development and PL/SQL background. Now I want to move towards web applications development. My dream is to create noncorporate web application for diet/training management with big focus on integration with experts, catering services/individual cooks, food shops/markets.

Very general description of an idea:

1. Diet management (plans, dishes creation etc)
2. Training management (plans, progress tracking etc)
3. Personal diet/training management or guided by experts
4. Community of clients, experts (gym instructors, dieters), catering services,  food shops etc).
5. Diet facilitated with catering services and local groceries
6. Training facilitated with mobile app (training to-do's, progress tracking, timer etc) (training data synchronised).

If you were Oracle Developer and would like to start a business of this kind in the future (maybe long future) would you go for Oracle Apex as a technology for your system or maybe better option would be Javascript and MEAN Stack for example? (larger community of developers as potential coworkers, better suited for noncorporate systems? ). For me Apex looks very exciting and seems to be natural choise regarding my background. Choosing other technology would be longer journey for me but I'm also open for it.

Comment: This is too broad and opinion based a question. However, I will say that Apex is a good introduction to web application development for someone with a background in PL/SQL and/or Oracle Forms.

Comment: Build it in Apex so you can out of the door and see if the world likes or wants it. You can always build it again in another language\framework as a side project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle APEX is an excellent tool for creating a web application prototype with little to no coding experience, and very little design work.  It makes proof of concept/demos easy to make, and replicate.  As for designing a fully functional web app, with client access, I would reccommend taking the traditional route, using a different dev enviroment.  APEX does a lot of "magic" for you behind the scenes, and expects you, (the user) to trust that it knows best, and would never lead you astray.  But with a full blown web app, that lack of control over the details can make or break your journey.